# deploying a node.js application on windows

Tags: node.js

I have developed a node.js application. I have two files serverpart.js and index.html (the html file is already referenced in server.js). During my development I run the application using command **node serverpart.js** and then access the client using http://localhost/8070. That was nice but now my application is ready and I want it to be accessed from other machines on the LAN. So please advice where should put these files(in some particular director). Do I need any web server for that please suggest.

Comment: if you want to access it from computer on same network you can replace localhost with ip address and it will work.

Comment: You'll need a server. Either a computer you own, or one from the cloud. Heroku has free options and is notorious for auto-magically configuring everything for you. But still, if it's your first time setting up a server, expect an hour or two invested.

Comment: To add onto Solvenc1no 's comment, you need to expose your port (in this case 8070) so it is accessible.